# Unix (Cygwin) whatis: returns all commands as "nothing appropriate"

Tags: unix, command, cygwin

For some odd reason, the "whatis" command in my Unix shell (cygwin) is not working.  It constantly returns "ls: nothing appropriate" or "cd: nothing appropriate".  I'm wondering if there is something incorrectly set-up.  Does anyone have any light to shed?  Thanks!

Comment: What is output of `type whatis`?

Comment: It says "whatis is hashed (usr/bin/whatis).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [Cygwin FAQ](http://cygwin.com/faq-nochunks.html#faq.using.man):

> Why doesn't man -k (or apropos) work?
>
> Before you can use man -k or apropos, you must create the whatis database. Just run the command
>
> ```
> mandb
> ```
>
> (it may take a minute to complete).

(Note: It used to say `/usr/sbin/makewhatis` instead of `mandb` in older versions of that FAQ.)

Comment: `man` opens manual pages. `apropos` and `whatis` search an index for relevant manual pages. Try running `man man`, `man apropos` and `man whatis` for more details on what each of them do, and feel free to ask a new question if you're still stuck.

Comment: On Fedora, I had to run this as `sudo` for it to update

Answer (score 30):

I ran into a similar issue using the 64-bit [Red Hat Cygwin installation](http://www.redhat.com/services/custom/cygwin/).

In my case, `/usr/sbin/makewhatis` did not exist. Running `man` and a command worked, but neither `apropos` nor `whatis` returned anything other than "nothing appropriate".

After searching for a missing package and binging a bunch, I Read The Friendly Manual page for `man` and found out about `mandb`.

Running `mandb` solved my problem.

Comment: +1 In [MSYS2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/) too there wasn't a `makewhatis`, but `mandb` worked! Thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: This answer also applies to vanilla 64-bit Cygwin.

Answer (score 11):

Run `sudo mandb` once

Not sure if this helps, but when I ran `mandb`, I got this (over several attempts).

```
mandb    
0 man subdirectories contained newer manual pages.
0 manual pages were added.
0 stray cats were added.
0 old database entries were purged.
```

However,

```
sudo mandb
75 man subdirectories contained newer manual pages.
7235 manual pages were added.
0 stray cats were added.
0 old database entries were purged.
```

worked for real.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.
I fixed it by `#mandb` command.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was fixed by running #mandb command

```
[root@localhost log]# whatis last
last (1)             - show a listing of last logged in users
[root@localhost log]#
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo mandb solved the problem for me. It regenerates the apropos database, but you have to make sure you run it with sudo.